# Implementing Average method in custom Queue wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, queue, average

I have a Custom 'Lockable' Queue Class which wraps Queue. However it is missing an Average method.

This is the Average method I tried adding to the Class listed in the source link below

```
public float Average()
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                return queue.Average();
            }
        }
```

but get the following error on 'queue'

> Queue does not contain a definition for 'Average' and the best
>   method extension overload 'Enumerable.Average(IEnumerable)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'

Original source https://gist.github.com/jaredjenkins/5421892

Comment: Can you just iterate through the queue and take the average?

Comment: LINQ Average, without parameters, is defined only for queues of numeric types (int, float etc), and your queue is of arbitrary type T.

Comment: Can you use `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue` instead of rolling your own?

Comment: ConcurrentQue not available in Unity. What I need is some specific help on exactly how to turn my generic Queue into something that will work with Average.

Answer (score 0):

Since you clearly have some field or property that is defined within your class that you can aggregate over to get an average you can optionally define a lambda selector function in the constructor which would be used to evaluate at execution time. The only caveat is that the field/property must be publicly visible for reading as it's defined externally. This simple class should accomplish what you are trying to do. I did notice that the default return type for linq.Average() was double and not float. So I have changed this, but otherwise it should be adequate.

```
public class QueueT<T>
{
    public QueueT(Func<T, int> avgSelector)
    {
        selector = avgSelector;
    }

    private Func<T, int> selector;
    private object syncLock = new object();
    private Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();

    public double Average()
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            return (from item in queue select selector(item)).Average();
        }
    }

}
```

A sample type

```
public class Car
{
   //
   public int HP => 500;
}
```

Then when you are creating an instance

```
public class RealImplementationandUseClass
{
    public RealImplementationandUseClass()
    {
        var q = new QueueT<Car>((c) => c.HP);
    }
}
```

This way you can guarantee that a selector is available for the type at compile time and you don't have to put constraints on the generic type for your queue class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the source it looks like you could implement the method this way:

```
        public double Average()
        {
            return (from item in CopyToArray() select MakeNumberOrThrow(item)).Average();
        }

        private int MakeNumberOrThrow(object mightBeANumber)
        {
            return (int) mightBeANumber;
        }
```

As @Evk mentioned in a comment in order to use the LINQ Average() the type must be a number. There isn't a way to restrict a generic type to be a number in C#, so somehow you must convert the type to a number. Obviously this or any other methods won't be safe for all types that could be in the custom Queue wrapper.

Comment: @fanuc_bob's answer works if you know the types, and they can't be cast to int.